# wordpress wp query posts per page default

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here is the code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php
                    $temp = $wp_query;
                    $wp_query= null;
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                    $wp_query->query('showposts=5'.'&paged='.$paged);
                    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query- >the_post();
                ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php higher_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>


        <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I show posts per page not 5 but default? I mean post that we can set at back end at Reading Settings, Blog pages show at most - number of post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
global $numposts;
$wp_query->query( 'showposts='.$numposts.'&paged='.$paged );
```

Comment: `$numposts` is not guaranteed to be set. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The safest way is to call `get_option`, which gets the value directly from the database:

```
$showposts = get_option('posts_per_page');
$wp_query->query('showposts='.$showposts.'&paged='.$paged);
```

Global variables like `$numposts` are not guaranteed to be set.

For future reference, you can usually determine what to pass to `get_option` by finding the `name` attribute of the setting's `<input>` in WP Admin.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. OP wanted to avoid hard-coding the 5.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), it does not have any default value for the number of posts per page.

You should however note that `showposts` has been replaced by `posts_per_page` in your code:

```
$wp_query->query('showposts=5'.'&paged='.$paged);
```